# /deep/ concept multiple page effect same scss .but i don't want effect for one page in angulars

Tags: css, angular, sass, scss-lint

In my shared folder . Auth  folder. components are there in auth .we write some css  in 'auth.component.scss',it is like parent  to all components  it will affect  all component  scss, but i don't  wont effect  'y' component  means  all pages effecting  max width :'35rem'   but i want **seperate** for this page  width:100% ;  if  i use /deep/ concept . when  'y' component loads width :100% effecting ,after returning to  another  component  it will not change to actual max width 35 rem

Comment: Did you tried with view encapsulation setting to none for your y component ?

Comment: yes .but it is getting an error  ts lint . it can't  load a page.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a specific class to children where you want/don't want the child to be applied.

```
::ng-deep container .page
{
    max-width: 35rem; /* Max width for all page elements */
}

::ng-deep container .apply .page
{
    /* Max width for all page elements which have a parent with 
    max-width: 35rem; 'apply' class*/
}

::ng-deep container :not(.dont-apply) .page
{
  /* Max width for all page elements except these which have a parent with 'dont-apply' class*/
    max-width: 35rem; 
}
```

Comment: this all content need to  add in a parent  scss ?

Comment: Not necessarily. But if you want these styles to only apply to child components of a parent component, you need to use `:host ::ng-deep .....`

Comment: thanks for answer .. i'm new  for this deep concept
i'm  done with another  way    by using <router -outer>  divided  parent and child   by using the condtion  window.location.path  by using path i put an condtion  to  divide components ..any way thanks

Comment: do you know recordrtc? is there any refrence   code send me please !!

Comment: Accept this answer if it solved your problem and open another question if it's something unrelated